# Nginx subdirectory root issue

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a webroot at `/usr/local/nginx/html`. (localhost)

I have a WordPress installation at `/usr/local/nginx/html/hi.com/public`.

I want to access the WordPress installation from `http://localhost/hi.com`.

Here's my configuration that is messing up:

```
  location /hi.com {
      root /usr/local/nginx/html/hi.com/public;
  }
```

When I go to `http://localhost/hi.com/humans.txt` it tries to grab `humans.txt` from `/usr/local/nginx/html/hi.com/public/hi.com/humans.txt` and not from the desired `/usr/local/nginx/html/hi.com/public/humans.txt` location.

Any idea on how I fix this?

kill me already.

Comment: Can you please post the entire Nginx configuration, it may helps.

Comment: https://github.com/TimeTravelersHackMe/nginx-configs

Comment: It's under sites-available/default

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're using `root` instead of `alias`.

- `root` will work in this way ([Nginx guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root)):

  ```
  location /hi.com/ {
      root /usr/local/nginx/html/hi.com/public/;
  }
  ```

  - GET: `http://localhost/hi.com/humans.txt`
  - RESPONSE: `/usr/local/nginx/html/hi.com/public/hi.com/humans.txt`
- `alias` will work in this way ([Nginx guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)):

  ```
  location /hi.com/ {
      alias /usr/local/nginx/html/hi.com/public/;
  }
  ```

  - GET: `http://localhost/hi.com/humans.txt`
  - RESPONSE: `/usr/local/nginx/html/hi.com/public/humans.txt`

For this purpose the right choice is to use `alias`.